Consistent order in grouped bar plot with missing data with `geom_bar`
I am trying to plot grouped bar plots with ggplot2 as below.
library(ggplot2)

data(mtcars)
mtcars$gear <- as.factor(mtcars$gear)

mtcars$carb <- as.factor(mtcars$carb)


ggplot() +
geom_bar(data = mtcars, aes(x = carb), alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_bar(data = mtcars, mapping = aes(x = carb, fill = gear),
           position = position_dodge(preserve = "single"))


When there is missing data in a group, then the position of the bars are not consistent. The bars are pushed to the leftmost position.
How to plot group-wise bar plots in such cases with consistent positions of the bars ?

Consistent positions of the bars would seem like you need to map the x-axis to the "gear" variable, not the "carb" variable. However, you're already mapping the x-axis to the "carb" variable in the overall barplot. Hence, your dilemma.
One possible workaround is to use geom_rect for the overall "carb" bars (after counting) and then facet on "carb". We can then use the "gear" variable for the x-axis, and they will remain in their fixed or "consistent" positions.
library(ggplot2)
library(ddplyr)

count(mtcars, carb) |>
  ggplot() +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = 0.5, xmax=3.5, ymin=0, ymax=n), alpha = 0.2) +
  facet_grid(~carb, switch="x") +
  geom_bar(data = mtcars, mapping = aes(x = gear, fill = gear)) +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_blank(), axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
        strip.background = element_rect(fill=NA)) +
  labs(x="carb") +
  scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0))

Giving

xmax=3.5 in geom_rect is the number of factor levels in "gear" + 0.5.
